# How to generate random Int in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, random, io, int

i'm trying to generate a random index (Int), with this code: `randomRIO (0, 2 :: Int)`. But its generate a IO Int, so i cant do something like this: `[1,2,3] !! randomIndex`. What does it have to be done to convert the IO Int to Int? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...this code: `randomRIO (0, 2 :: Int)`. But its generate a `IO Int`...

no, it **is** an `IO Int` value. Such a value is similar to a “function” `int f()` in a procedural language. If this were, say, Python, then you could also not just write

```py
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import random

In [2]: def f():
   ...:     return random.randint(0,2)
   ...: 

In [3]: [1,2,3][f]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-74d3c2a164a4> in <module>()
----> 1 [1,2,3][f]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not function
```

Instead, you need to *invoke* the action. Only that will in fact yield an `Int` number. In most languages, this is done simply by supplying arguments, in this case just the empty tuple `()`:

```
In [4]: [1,2,3][f()]
Out[4]: 2
```

But that's mingling two different concepts, namely supplying arguments and causing side-effects. (The side-effect is in this case the modification of the built-in random generator's state, so you won't get every time the same number.)

Haskell does it better, it has dedicated operators for sorting out the order of side-effects. As Daniel Wagner said, these are `fmap` and `>>=`. But if those infix-operators and higher-order type signatures look cryptic to you, you can also use Haskell's `do` notation, which is actually just syntactic sugar for the same thing:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   randomIndex <- randomRIO (0,2)
   print $ [1,2,3] !! randomIndex
```

or, at the ghci prompt (which is essentially one big `IO`-`do`-block)

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Prelude> :m +System.Random
Prelude System.Random> randomIndex <- randomRIO (0,2 :: Int)
Prelude System.Random> [1,2,3] !! randomIndex
1
```

The difference between `foo <- action` and `let foo = action` is similar as in Python the difference between `foo = action()` and `foo = action`.

Comment: I have often wondered whether it is possible for beginners to make good use of `do` notation without first having a firm grasp of `(>>=)` or similar. sigfpe's [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html) article is the closest I've seen to a tutorial that takes that possibility seriously, so if you like this answer, I highly recommend it as a next step for understanding how to use `do` blocks properly.

Comment: but my real code is: `newCard:: Card
newCard = do
  index <- randomRIO(0,7)
  return  (getCards deck) !! index`
i want to return a Card, but it is IO Card

Comment: “i want to return a Card” – no you don't. Unless you want that every card in every game is the same.

Comment: @leftaroundabout so it's only possible to generate random numbers in the output? Thanks for your help. Is that I saw this System.Random package and thought I could use it to do things like this that I wanted ...

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert an `IO a` to an `a`; but you can convert a function which consumes an `a` into one that consumes an `IO a` instead. The two most important conversions are these:

```
(<$>) :: (a ->    b) -> (IO a -> IO b)
(=<<) :: (a -> IO b) -> (IO a -> IO b)
```

Since the function you want to use, namely, `\index -> [1,2,3] !! index`, does not have an `IO` return type, `(<$>)` is the more appropriate one for you. So:

```
System.Random> (\index -> [1,2,3] !! index) <$> randomRIO (0, 2)
1
```